# Open interval $(0,1)$ is totally bounded

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is true that an open interval $(0,1)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ totally bounded?
I think it is  not true.

Since there is an homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is not totally bounded.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: Is "totally boundedness" a topological property then? (i.e. a property shared by homeomorphic spaces).

Comment: Work directly from the definition of totally bounded.

Answer (score 5):

It is true that $(0,1)$ is totally bounded, and this is a property of the metric (or of the uniformity, if you know about those), **not** of the topology. So it is not necessarily preserved by homeomorphisms (but it is by isometries!), as your own example in fact shows.

That $(0,1)$ is totally bounded can be seen in different ways: for $r>0$ we can cover $(0,1)$ by at most $1+\frac{1}{r}$ (I think, but at least is finite) many open intervals of length $r$ (which are also open balls in the metric). Or we can apply to a general theorem that $[0,1]$ is compact and a subset of a compact set is totally bounded as well.

The notion is not topological, and neither is completeness (same example, but now $(0,1)$ is not complete in the usual metric, but $\mathbb{R}$ is), but totally bounded plus completeness as a combined property (for metric or uniform spaces, where these notions are defined) is equivalent to compactness, which is topological (in the sense that a homeomorphic space to a compact one is also compact).